# Setting style to specific words in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a menu system utilizing Milonic menus, and need to set specific words in the menu to change style. for example, in the code

```
with(SampStyle=new mm_style()){
bordercolor="#000000";
borderstyle="solid";
borderwidth=0;
fontfamily="Amaranth, sans serif";
fontsize="17px";
fontstyle="normal";
fontweight="normal";
align='center';
offbgcolor="#000000";
offcolor="#ffffff";
onbgcolor="#333333";
oncolor="#ffffff";
pagecolor="#aaffaa";
padding=5;
itemwidth="100px";
}

with(milonic=new menuname("Main Menu")){
alwaysvisible=1;
top=0;
itemwidth="1%";

position:"relative;"
top=230;

/*left=199;*/
screenposition="center";
menuwidth="834px"; /* was 85%, to fit on page 70% -->68% */
/*screenposition="middle;center";
top="offset=-40";*/

orientation="horizontal";
style=SampStyle;
aI("text=Home;url=http://www.moe365.org/;");
aI("showmenu=News;text=News;url=http://moe365.org/news.php;");
aI("showmenu=FIRST Robotics;text=FIRST;url=http://www.moe365.org/whatisfirst.php;");
aI("showmenu=The Team;text=The&nbsp;Team;url=http://moe365.org/team.php;");
aI("showmenu=Media;text=Media;url=http://www.moe365.org/media.php;");
aI("showmenu=Competitions;text=Competitions;url=http://moe365.org/competitions.php;");
aI("showmenu=Robot History;text=Robots;url=http://moe365.org/history.php;");
aI("showmenu=Sponsors;text=Sponsors&nbsp;&nbsp;;url=http://moe365.org/sponsors.php;");
aI("showmenu=Resources;text=Resources;url=http://moe365.org/resources.php;");

}
```

i need the word "First" to change style. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Target the word and use the ".addClass" in jQuery like so:

```
/* etc */ 
yourWord.addClass("colorClass");
/* etc */
```

Linked reference:
http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Or wrap the word in a span tag like this:

```
<span class="colorClass">FIRST</span>
```

and in your css:

```
.colorClass {
    color:red; /* or the color you want */
}
```

Comment: it did not work for me, do you have any other ideas?